# Bizarre behavior with SIN LTSpice

Tags: transistors, ltspice

I have this circuit I'm supposed to analyze. I am asked to set v1 to a sine wave V1= A sin (2pi f t) with a frequency f = 1 kHz and A = 5mV. I think I did everything right, but when I run the simulation I have 2 issues:

Edit: I just realized that it should be SIN(0 0.005 1k), but it doesn't change my problem.

[image]

One: It takes REALLY long to simulate, like much longer than all my other circuits and most importantly,

Two: Instead of showing a sine wave, I get this instead:

[image]

It should, however, show a normal sine wave. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Two million farads capacitance makes settling time very l-o-n-g. No such physical capacitors exist (Maybe the earth does),

Comment: @glen_geek  As well as being a bit inconvenient to use, the earth apparently has a capacitance of around 711uF.

Comment: Your capacitors are ridiculously large, which causes simulation problems, and you're looking at the first 50 or 60usec of a 1ms sine wave, which is going to look pretty much like an almost-straight line.

Comment: @glen_geek @SpehroPefhany Large capacitors are a standard simulation technique; the time constant is irrelevant as long as DC `.op` is enabled and has been solved correctly (and this circuit shouldn't be complicated enough to cause such problems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simulator is doing exactly what it was told to do.

The capacitors are 2000000 farads, which means that the RC timeconstant will be roughly 9.2 billion seconds or 291 years, so simulating 10 seconds and graphing a few 10's of us won't show that capacitor charging much.

According to [Quora the largest capacitor ever made](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-largest-capacitor-ever-made-and-what-was-its-purpose) was 30000F

Comment: 2-many-farads ‍

Comment: and @SteKulov , do people really just *not know* about simulation techniques?

Answer (score 1):

What the plot shows is pretty much what you'd expect, even if you didn't have the ridiculously large capacitors. You have a 1 kHz sine wave and your plot shows 70 µs of it. That's about 1/14th of a cycle or around 25\$^\circ\$.